# HTTP POST request - How to pass parameters after the page is completed

Tags: uwp, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using HttpClient with the Windows.Web.Http namespace in a UWP.
I can create post requests with parameters as field values for an uri by means of the content of the request and the SendRequest method. The response is successfull.

For another uri, some parameters are not taken into account probably because the field values are initialized in the page (I can see the initialization in the source code). Or, maybe, because the page content is varying according to one parameter which is succesfully taken into account. So that the fields may be not present at the beginning of the page loading.

Do you know how to pass parameters after the page loading is completed?

Comment: So, did you need to post your request to the page uri again when the page loading  is completed?

Comment: In fact, I need to post the page uri one time just after the page loading, first step, and after all the parameters are transmitted and taken into account in the page, 2nd step. <br/> In the meantime, or if a solution cannot be found with HttpClient, I use an hidden WebView control, fill the fields, and execute the scripts with the InvokeScriptAsync method.

Comment: Yes. Using a hidden WebView is a good idea. Please try it.